# Prolog - Change elements of a list

Tags: list, prolog

Complete beginner doing exercises from a book, I want take a list `X` and change its elements so that for some `[H|X]` the new list `Y` would have the `HEAD` element be `(H-1,H+1)`.

Something like:

```
X=[1,20,300] --> Y=[(0,2),(19,21),(299,301)]
```

What I have so far add's the first element, but then returns some weird "_number". What I have so far:

```
switch([], []).
switch([H|X], Y) :-
   H1 is H-1,
   H2 is H+1,
   append([(H1,H2)], [], Y).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. `append`ing `[(H1, H2)]` and `[]` gives us a result that we can know in advance: `Y` will be `[(H1, H2)]` as well;
2. you do not do anything with the tail `X` in this case, so you only process the first element, and then throw away that element.

Your predicate will thus just process the first element, and create a list with that tuple, like:

```
?- switch([1,2,3], Y).
Y = [(0, 2)].
```

In fact we do not need `append/3` at all here: we have two parameters, and if the former one is non-empty, then the latter is non-empty as well and vice versa. So our recursive clause has the shape:

```
switch([], []).
switch([H|T], [(H1, H2)|TT]) :-
    %% ...
```

We thus need to specify the relation between `H` and `H1` and `H2`; and `T` and `TT` (the rest of the elements of the "tuple list"). As for `H`, this is already implemented `H1 is H-1` and `H2 is`H+1`. As for`T`and`TT`, we just need to continue processing, so we make a recursive call with`T`and`TT`:

```
switch([], []).
switch([H|T], [(H1, H2)|TT]) :-
    H1 is H-1,
    H2 is H+1,
    switch(T, TT).
```

## Using [**`clpfd`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=summary-lib-clpfd)

Here we only can query in one direction: if we unify a list of 2-tuples with the second argument, then Prolog can not derive the elements in the first list. We can however define constraints between these elements, and as a result, we can query in several directions:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

switch([], []).
switch([H|T], [(H1, H2)|TT]) :-
    H1 #= H-1,
    H2 #= H+1,
    switch(T, TT).
```

We now can query for example with:

```
?- switch(L, [(1, A), (3, 5), (C, 7)]).
L = [2, 4, 6],
A = 3,
C = 5.
```

## Working with [**`maplist/3`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3)

The task we are solving is a typical "mapping task". So we can "*scrap our boilerplate*", and use [**`maplist/3`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

switch_tuple(H, (H1, H2)) :-
    H1 #= H-1,
    H2 #= H+1.

switch(L1, L2) :-
    maplist(switch_tuple, L1, L2).
```

Comment: Thank you very much with this detailed answer. I have been struggling with list manipulation, your explanation seems good!